# using for-loop to pass string values of an array in umbraco

Tags: c#, razor, for-loop, umbraco

I am trying to pass the array value one by one to the image

```
<img src="@crops.Find("@name", "boxes[0]").url" alt="" />
```

for instance for first time the boxes[0] = box-1x1 , similarly when the

```
foreach (var node in Model.Children)
```

loop runs second time the box value should be boxes[1] which is box-2x1 , i just can think of a way how to run for loop to pass these values 8 times as the array size is 0-8

```
 @{ @* Initialize box styles:list.Add(node.UrlName);*@
    string[] boxes = { "box-1x1", "box-2x1", "box-1x1" , "box-2x1" ,"box-2x2", "box-1x2", "box-1x1" , "box-2x1","box-1x1" };
    var list = new List<string>();
    foreach (var node in Model.Children)
        {
            dynamic croping = @Model.mainImage.mediaItem.Image.mediaCropper;
            foreach (dynamic crops in croping)
                {   
                    if (crops.GetType().ToString() != "System.String")
                            {   
                                <img src="@crops.Find("@name", "boxes[0]").url" alt="" />
                            }   
                }   
        }

 }
```

Can any one provide me with any assistance or suggestion.
Any help will be appreciated
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want an index in your loop, use a `for` loop, not `foreach`.
Alternatively, define an `int index = 0` variable before your `foreach` loop and advance it by 1 after each iteration.

For example:

```
int index = 0;
foreach (var node in Model.Children)
{
    // Do your stuff
    // ...
    <img src="@boxes[index]" />
    // ...

    index++;
}
```

Comment: but how can i limit index to 9

Comment: Why? If you have 9 items in your collection it will go from 0 to 8. If you have 500 items in your collection, you'll get `box-500`. Where does the 9 limit come in here?